# meaning of "niggling" in "niggling restrictions and regulations"?

Tags: meaning

Which word is closer in meaning to the word "niggling" in the phrase "niggling restrictions and regulations"?

1. bothering
2. petty

The verb "to niggle" has two meanings.

More context:

> That this desire is in accordance with justice, it is impossible to deny; but something larger and more constructive is needed as a political ideal, if the victors of to-morrow are not to become the oppressors of the day after. The inspiration and outcome of a reforming movement ought to be freedom and a generous spirit, not **niggling restrictions and regulations**.

Comment: Can't tell without more context. "restrictions and regulations" could be bothering and/or petty (you don't like them vs. being unimportant).

Comment: @user3169, I added some more context. The phrase appears at the end of a long paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

> The inspiration and outcome of a reforming movement ought to be freedom and a generous spirit, not niggling restrictions and regulations.

The author seems to point out that a '*reforming movement*', like a revolution, instead of give the people a sense of freedom, hope and general positive outlook for an impending future of the society, gives people a sense of being restricted and told what to do.

As for the term '**[niggle](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=niggling&oq=niggling&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)**', I think the meaning of '*uncomfortable*' and '*annoying*' are more fitting, in this context.